# Where are blocks like hoppers, sculk sensors/ shreekers rendered(and how to cancel them all)

Tags: render, mixins, minecraft-fabric

I am using Fabric 1.20.1 and trying to find out where blocks like these are rendered and how to modify it or cancel it.

right now I am cancelling all blocks and blockentities from being rendered, and still the top half of the sculk stuff stays and parts of the bell and hopper.

I noticed that the blocks affected were so far:
Sculk Sensor/ Shreeker, Bell, Hopper, Enchanting table, Beacon, Lecturn, Campfire

I tried canceling all BlockEntityRenderDispatcher render methods separately and that didn't fix it.

I also tried seeing what they had in common and didn't see anything consistent.

What is the quickest way to cancel these blocks from being rendered with a mixin?